# Campo select django wagtail cms

Tags: django

Un saludo a todos

Estoy usando una librería llamada wagtail y necesito crear un formulario, este contiene un campo select y necesito que las opciones de este se puedan personalizar

Lo quiero es poder tener en mi formulario opciones como si se tratara de una foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

Encontré que creando el formulario se pueden generar los campos en administrador de wagtail.

```
class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='form_fields')


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    landing_page_template = 'contacto/form_page.html'

    # titulos
    titulo_formulario = RichTextField(blank=True)
    subtitulo_formulario = RichTextField(blank=True)

    # soporte
    correo_electronico_soporte = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    codigo_pais_telefono = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    telefono_soporte = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FormSubmissionsPanel(),
        FieldPanel('titulo_formulario'),
        FieldPanel('subtitulo_formulario'),
        FieldPanel('correo_electronico_soporte'),
        FieldPanel('codigo_pais_telefono'),
        FieldPanel('telefono_soporte'),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]
```